# How to Optimize MYSQL in Extra :-Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-administration

What is the proper indexing for this query.

I tried given different combinations of indexes for this query but it is still using from using tempory , using filesort etc.

Total table data - 7,60,346

`product`= 'Dresses' - Total rows = 122 554

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_data` (
  `table_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `discount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `availability` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `table_id` (`table_id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `discount` (`discount`),
  KEY `step_one` (`product`,`availability`),
  KEY `step_two` (`product`,`availability`,`brand`,`store`),
  KEY `step_three` (`product`,`availability`,`brand`,`store`,`id`),
  KEY `step_four` (`brand`,`store`),
  KEY `step_five` (`brand`,`store`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Query :

```
SELECT id ,store,brand FROM `product_data` WHERE product='dresses' and 
availability='1' group by brand,store order by store limit 10;
```

> excu..time :-   (10 total, Query took 1.0941 sec)

EXPLAIN PLAN :

---

possible_keys :- **step_one, step_two, step_three, step_four, step_five**

key :-  **step_two**

ref :- **const,const**

rows :- **229438**

Extra :-**Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort**

I tried these indexes

---

`Key` step_one (`product`,`availability`)

`Key` step_two (`product`,`availability`,`brand`,`store`)

`Key` step_three (`product`,`availability`,`brand`,`store`,`id`)

`Key` step_four (`brand`,`store`)

`Key` step_five (`brand`,`store`,`id`)

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE product_data` output in your question.

Comment: @kuldeepupadhyay please give us the time results for each of the indexes combination , you've mentionned

Comment: @ Andy K yes sir my query pick second index they Query took 1.0941 sec

Comment: they pick automic step-two  i think this is best combination , but still time more and using tempory ,using filesort

Comment: @kuldeepupadhyay in your question I mean

Comment: @Andy K sir i create all combinations MYSQL pick automic Step_two

Comment: I doubt you will be able to get rid of "using temporary ,using filesort" as the where condition, group and order are quite disparate,  but have you tried `brand,store,product,availability`. Though as I say I doubt it will make much difference.

Comment: @Jaydee ok sir i trie now and tell the reponce

Comment: What is "group by" doing? It's usually only relevant with aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is not the index, but the mismatch between `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` preventing taking advantage of `LIMIT`.

This

```
INDEX(product, availability, store, brand, id)
```

will be "covering" and in the right order.  But note that I have swapped `store` and `brand`...

Change the query to

```
SELECT  id ,store,brand
    FROM  `product_data`
    WHERE  product='dresses'
      and  availability='1'
    GROUP BY store, brand    -- change
    ORDER BY store, brand    -- change
    limit  10;
```

That changes the `GROUP BY` to start with `store`, to reflect the `ORDER BY` ordering -- this avoid an extra sort.  And it  changes the `ORDER BY` to be identical to the `GROUP BY` so that the two can be combined.

Given those changes, the `INDEX` can now go all the way through to the `LIMIT`, thereby allowing the processing to look at only 10 rows, not a much larger set.

Anything less than all these changes will not be as efficient.

Further discussion:

```
INDEX(product, availability,   -- these two can be in either order
      store, brand,      -- must match both `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`
      id)   -- tacked on (on the end) to make it "covering"
```

"Covering" means that *all* the columns for the `SELECT` are found in the `INDEX`, so no need to reach over into the data.

But...  *The whole query does not make sense* because of the inclusion of `id` in the `SELECT`.  If you want to find what stores have available dresses, then get rid of `id`.  If you want to list all the available dresses, then change `id` to `GROUP_CONCAT(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

For the indexes, the best index is the step_two. The product field is used in where and has more variation than the availability-field.

Couple of notes about the query:

1. availability='1' should be availability=1 so that needless int->varchar conversion would be avoided.
2. "group by brand" should not be used as GROUP BY should only be used when you use aggregate functions as selected columns. What as it that you were trying to achieve with the group by?

Comment: yes sir i tried " SELECT id,brand " but still using tempory,using filesort. Please help

Comment: What as it that you were trying to achieve with the group by?

Answer (score 1):

Your `group by clause` doesn't really make sense without an aggregate function.

If you can re-write the query to

```
SELECT id ,store 
FROM `product_data` 
WHERE product='dresses' 
and availability='1' 
order by store limit 10;
```

Then an index on `(`product`,`availability`,`store`)` will remove all filesorts.

See SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60f33d/2

UPDATE:

The SQLFiddle makes your intention clear - you're using `GROUP BY` to simulate `DISTINCT`. I don't think you can get rid of the filesort and temporary table steps in your query if this is the case -  but I also don't think those steps should be hugely expensive.

Comment: This does not match the original request since it fails to do the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `GROUP BY` has the effect of `DISTINCT` in the absence of aggregates.  But `DISTINCT` will stumble over the unique `id`.