# Optimize MYSQL in Extra :-Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration, query-performance

What is the proper indexing ? i rewrite query and table for batter understanding.

I tried given different combinations of indexes for this query but it is still using from using tempory , using filesort etc.

```
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_data` 
     (`table_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `store` varchar(255) NOT  NULL,  
    `brand` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
     `product` varchar(255)  NOT NULL, 
    `gender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
     `availability` int(11) NOT  NULL,  
     PRIMARY KEY (`table_id`),  
     UNIQUE KEY `table_id`  (`table_id`),  
     KEY `id` (`id`),  
     KEY `step_one`  (`product`,`availability`), 
      KEY `step_two`  (`product`,`availability`,`brand`,`store`), 
      KEY `step_three`  (`product`,`availability`,`brand`,`store`,`id`), 
      KEY `step_four`  (`brand`,`store`),   KEY `step_five` (`brand`,`store`,`id`) ) 
 ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Query :

```
SELECT id ,store FROM `test_data` WHERE product='dresses' and availability=1
 group by brand order by store limit 10;
```

check live database http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5280b1/1

Comment: You probably don't have a problem. `temporary` and `filesort` are often inherent in ordered aggregate queries. Read this: https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/   If your query performance  is unsatisfactory, read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then return here and [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: @O. Jones ok sir

Comment: Also, you can remove redundant indexes.  Your most complex by product, availability, brand, store, id  (step_three) could still be used IN PLACE of step_two and step_one indexes as the fields are same order.  I am sure this was just a test to try and help optimize the query.

Comment: You changed the query slightly, but [_my answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46494697/1766831) still works.